# pandas combine rows of strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Index   User    Message
1       User1   This is
2       User1   a test.
3       User2   The test
4       User2   is received.
5       User1   This is a complete sentence.
6       User2   This is another complete sentence.
7       User1   Finished.
```

I need a way to **combine the messages when a user sends more than one message** before the other while keeping the original order.

Desired output:

```
Index   User    Message
1       User1   This is a test.
2       User2   The test is received
3       User1   This is a complete sentence.
4       User2   This is another complete sentence.
5       User1   Finished.
```

Is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = (df.groupby([df['User'].ne(df['User'].shift(1)).cumsum().values, 'User'])['Message']
        .agg(' '.join).reset_index(level=1))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.